# Command showing different behaviour when running from terminal and when Using as Shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

I am using KUbuntu 18.04.1

I am trying to extract text from screenshot using spectacle (Screenshot app of KUbuntu) & gocr (OCR tool)

If I give the commands one after another in Konsole (Terminal of KUbuntu)

**First:**

```
spectacle -r -b -n -o /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg
```

**Second:**

```
gocr -i /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg | xsel -b
```

**It Works.**

if I create a bash file *screen_ts.sh* and put the code

```
#!/bin/bash
# Dependencies: gocr xsel

# Take Screenshot and Save it to a File
spectacle -r -b -n -o /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg

# Extract text from the saved file
gocr -i /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg | xsel -b

exit
```

Open Konsole and type *./screen_ts.sh* , **it works**

But, if I Make the file executable and double click, **it take screenshot but does not save the text in clipboard.**

Again if I create a custom shortcut using

Custom Shortcut > Trigger `Alt + Q` & Action `/home/UserName/Documents/Translate/screen_ts.sh`

[image: KUbuntu Custom Shortcut]

**it take screenshot but does not save the text in clipboard.** *Same behavior as double click.*

What is going on here?

Comment: Could you try after adding a small `sleep` between the two commands or maybe chain the two commands using `&&` to ensure the first command is completed before the second is run?

Comment: I tried both options earlier. I used sleep 1. Moreover, I checked in different answers here that `;`, command in different line actually works one after another.

Comment: What happens if you force execution in a terminal using `konsole -e gocr ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [man xsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel):

> By default, this program outputs the selection without modification if
>   both standard input and standard output are terminals (ttys).
>   Otherwise, the current selection is output if standard output is not a
>   terminal (tty), and the selection is set from standard input if
>   standard input is not a terminal (tty). If any input or output options
>   are given then the program behaves only in the requested mode.

This is a bit misleading, but there is an interesting comment in the [source code](https://github.com/kfish/xsel/blob/master/xsel.c):

> Checking stdin/stdout for being a tty is NOT reliable
>   to tell what the user wants. This is because child processes
>   inherit the file descriptors of their parents; an xsel called in
>   a script that is e.g. daemonized (not attached to a tty), or called
>   with a redirection or in a pipeline will have non-tty file descriptors on default. The redirection/piping issue also applies
>   to "grouped" or "compound" commands in the shell (functions,
>   subshells, curly-brace blocks, conditionals, loops, etc.). **In all
>   these cases, the user *must* set the mode of operation explicitly.**

...and that's the solution: tell `xsel` explicitly to read from `stdin` by adding the `-i` option:

```
gocr -i /home/UserName/Documents/Translate/input.jpg | xsel -b -i
```

Comment: That works and fixes the custom shortcut key route. Thanks!